# How to clear viewmodel when a user logout?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

The observer is not observing the livedata once user is logged out and logged in again. I think its somehow related to viewmodel scope because after restarting the appllciation it observers things again.

viewModel

```
package com.ashutosh.auth2.ui.viewmodel

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.ashutosh.auth2.models.Data
import com.ashutosh.auth2.models.Profile
import com.ashutosh.auth2.models.RecentLinks
import com.ashutosh.auth2.models.TopLinks
import com.ashutosh.auth2.repository.UserRepository
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val repository: UserRepository,
        private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    ) : ViewModel() {
    val  usersLiveData : LiveData<Data>
    get() = repository.data

    private val _response = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val response: LiveData<String> = _response

    init{
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getUsersData()
        }
    }

    fun createLink(app : String , link : String) {
        val recentLink = RecentLinks(link,0,app)
        val topLinks = TopLinks()
        val id = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid
        val data = Data(id.toString(), listOf(recentLink), listOf(topLinks))
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = repository.createLink(data)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                _response.value = "User created successfully"
            } else {
                _response.value = "Failed to create user"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Recycler data class

```
package com.ashutosh.auth2.ui.fragments

import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.ashutosh.auth2.R
import com.ashutosh.auth2.databinding.FragmentRecentLinkBinding
import com.ashutosh.auth2.ui.viewmodel.MainViewModel
import com.ashutosh.auth2.adapter.tabLayout.RecentLinkAdapter
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class RecentLinkFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var binding : FragmentRecentLinkBinding
    lateinit var mainViewMdoel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_recent_link,container,false)
        mainViewMdoel =ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        return binding.root
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mainViewMdoel.usersLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            binding.recyclerRecentLink.apply {
                adapter = RecentLinkAdapter(it.recent_links,requireContext())
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

repository

```
package com.ashutosh.auth2.repository

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.ashutosh.auth2.models.Data
import com.ashutosh.auth2.models.Id
import com.ashutosh.auth2.models.Profile
import com.ashutosh.auth2.retrofit.LinkProApi
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.gson.Gson
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Response
import javax.inject.Inject

class UserRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val linkProApi: LinkProApi,
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    ) {
    private val _data = MutableLiveData<Data>()
    val data : LiveData<Data>
    get() = _data

    suspend fun getUsersData() {
        try {
            val result = linkProApi.getLinkData(Id(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid.toString()))
            if (result.isSuccessful && result.body()  != null) {
                var gson = Gson()
                var data : Data = gson.fromJson(result.body()!!.string(),Data::class.java)
                _data.postValue(data)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("data", e.toString())
        }
    }

    suspend fun createLink(data: Data): Response<ResponseBody> {
        return linkProApi.createLink(data)
    }
}
```

Login and Logout

```
   fun signInWithGoogle(requestCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                var editor = sharedPreferences!!.edit()
                editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn",true)
                editor.apply()
                _isSignedIn.postValue(true)
                _signInResult.postValue(Resource.Success(account))
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                _signInResult.postValue(Resource.Failure(e))
            }
        }
    }

    fun logout(){
        firebaseAuth.signOut()
        _loginFlow.value = null
        _signupFlow.value = null
        userRepository.clearLiveData()
        var editor = sharedPreferences!!.edit()
        editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn",false)
        editor.apply()
        
    }
```

The observer in RecentLinkFragment do not observer when user gets logout and login again.
And if i restart the app it works fine.
Please help!!

Comment: You've shown no code for log in / log out. From what you do show, it would seem you only call `getUserData` in the view model constructor. So you would need to make sure you're calling that when you log in as well.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try.

First, add a method to clear the LiveData in MainViewModel.

```
fun clearLiveData() {
    _data.value = null
}
```

Then, call `clearLiveData` in RecentLinkFragment where you handle the logout.

Comment: This didn't work. Whenever I add a new item in a list, recycler view works properly. But if User logs out and log in again the list is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly share the logout / login code.

Once a fragment is popped out, viewModel will also be removed.

Observing LiveData with "viewLifecycleOwner" will work till view is destroyed.